# Store value in chrome extension after user signup or login

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am creating a chrome extension in that i have requirement like when user click for signup or login from chrome extension then after successful process of signup or login.I want to store one **user_key** in chrome extensions which key will be generated from website.

Signup & Login process will be done on new tab.

***Friends I want to know about flow only rather than code.***

Thanks,

Comment: Please describe what you have tried already and where the exact problem is.

Comment: Please provide minimal, completed, verifiable code. If you encountered any error, post your error logs. For the meantime, you may check this SO ticket, it discuss how to save information locally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364062/how-can-i-save-information-locally-in-my-chrome-extension

Comment: Hi,friends I want just to ask about flow other things i will mangae