# Javascript Variable not updating/saving

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a string which I need in multiple functions. Therefore I want to save it in a variable. 
But when I try to assign it inside a function it doesn't update the variable.

```
var auth_code = "na";
function safeAuthCode(authcode){
  auth_code = authcode;
  console.log(auth_code);
}
```

"`auth_code`" prints just fine in the console at that point, but when I try to use it later it just contains "na". 
Not sure what I'm doing wrong tbh :/

Edit:

This is the function in which safeAuthCode is called:

```
function auth(){
  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    "url": "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id="+client_id+
    "&redirect_uri="+ encodeURIComponent(redirectUri) +
    "&response_type=code"+
    "&scope=" + encodeURIComponent(scopes),
    "interactive": true
  },
  function(redirect_url) {
    var url = new URL(redirect_url);
    var code = url.searchParams.get("code");
    safeAuthCode(code);
  });
}
```

Comment: There isn't sufficient code available to make an educated guess, if you make a [mcve] you could possibly exclude why this is happening

Comment: Could it be possible that you are creating the variable in more than 1 part of your code? Maybe the saved value gets overwritten in the future. This kind of data should possibly be saved into `sessionStorage` though, that would make a lot more sense. You could then use `getItem` and `setItem` when reading / saving it

Comment: No, it's only set once. The code is part of a chrome extension. Am I still able to use session storage? "window.sessionStorage.setItem('authcode', auth_code);" and "console.log(window.sessionStorage.getItem('authcode'));" just returns null :/

Comment: Oh, it wasn't clear from the tags or the question that your code is an extension. There is however the `chrome.storage` object, that can be used to save data

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the problem you are having is because of the global variable that either gets overwritten in a different part of the code, or because your code at a certain point in time reloads, and the initial value gets reset.

To save such authentication code, you could make use of the [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) object of your browser.

To make sure you only have 1 such object, you could use the [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) keyword to define your variables (in case another definition of that variable would come at a later time, you should get an error thrown)

```
const authorisationSettings = {
  get code() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('authorisationCode') || 'na';
  },
  set code(value) {
    return sessionStorage.setItem('authorisationCode');
  }
};

function saveAuthorisationCode( code ) {
  authorisationSettings.code = code;
}

saveAuthorisationCode( 'test' );
console.log( authorisationSettings.code );
```

This snippet doesn't work on stackoverflow, so you can find the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ubt5487w/)

Comment: Still just prints out "na"

Comment: Yeah, that is probably because of the fact that you use it inside the chrome extensions

Comment: Alright, I think i got things sorted out, endet up using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5370400/7313569

Answer (score -2):

It happens because of when your function is executed, in lexical environment of that function is already exist `authcode` variable and you are trying to set this one instead of global `authcode`

You need to change name of global variable or param of the fuction...

Comment: the global is called `auth_code` and seems to be set inside the function, and is named different from the parameter...

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. I called that function in another function passing the variable authcode which was called differently in that function. I also tried renaming it