# How to store user password in browser extension?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a browser extension. I want to store user credential somewhere so that he don't have to input them again and again.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
    if (inputVal === "ramo") {
        text.style.display = "none";
        chrome.tabs.update({ url: "https://www.youtube.com" });
    } else {
        toggleText();
    }

});
```

I am getting user input password in `inputVal`  .. Now I want to store it . How to proceed further?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364062/how-can-i-save-information-locally-in-my-chrome-extension

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage or chrome.storage to store data, but with DevTools they can be referenced by third parties.